# How to calculate the entropy of a coin flip

Tags: math, encoding, statistics, probability, entropy

I would like to know ...

In the repeated coin flip, ¿how do I calculate the entropy of the random variable X that represents the number of flips to do until get "head" for first time?

Comment: what do you know about X ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `X` can take any number from 1 through infinity. The probabilities are:

```
p(X = i) = (1/2)^i
```

The entropy is:

```
H = - Sum {i from 1 to infinity} ( p(X = i) * log2(p(X = i)) )
  = - Sum {i from 1 to infinity} ( 1/2^i * log2(1/2^i) )
  = - Sum {i from 1 to infinity} ( 1/2^i * i * log2(1/2) )
  =   Sum {i from 1 to infinity} ( 1/2^i * i )
```

Solving this yields:

```
H = 2 bit
```